# Access2019/365 VBA DoCmd.OutputTo Error 2501 only on customer's laptop

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

this post is an continuation of my article
[DoCmd.OutputTo just stops after some rows when creating PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990312/docmd-outputto-just-stops-after-some-rows-when-creating-pdfs)

still have error 2501 on the line with DoCmd.OutputTo... - but ONLY on customer Laptop

What I did until now:

- setup a VM with Win11x64Pro and Microsoft 365 - same environment like my customer's laptop

  the default printer here is "Microsoft Print to PDF" and Windows manages default printers
  executed my Access2019 application - now with Access365 - with the code lines you see in my 1st post

> DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRptName, acFormatPDF, sFilePDF, , , , acExportQualityPrint

=> the procedure runs smoothly - no errors

- also changed the default printer on customer laptop to Microsoft Print to PDF - no success here: Windows manages NOT default printers;
- the default printer is connected via WLAN (HP ColorLaserJet M255dw)
- compared the version numbers of Microsoft 365; customer and my VM have installed:

Microsoft® Access® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20196) 32 Bit

- and the target folder is added to Trusted Locations

and now I'm stuck

resumee:

1. app runs with Access2019
2. app runs with Access365 in my VM
3. app runs NOT with Access365 on customer laptop

---

so far the error still exists and I have only limited timeslots with access to my customers laptop.

here again the vba code:

```
    Public Function fctPrintPDFs() as Long
.
.
.
             DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:=strRptName _
                    , View:=acViewPreview _
                    , Filtername:="" _
                    , WhereCondition:="" _
                    , WindowMode:=acHidden


            DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputReport _
                        , ObjectName:="" _
                        , OutputFormat:=acFormatPDF _
                        , OutputFile:=strRetCompletePathPDF _
                        , AutoStart:=False _
                        , OutputQuality:=acExportQualityPrint

          
            DoCmd.Close acReport, strRptName, acSaveNo

.
.
.

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        mstrMsg = "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: " & cAktProc & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.description & _
               Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl)
        MsgBox mstrMsg, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

and tried another forums tipp -> still error 2501

I also tried AutoStart: true and false
and to omit the ObjectName when using SelectObject

```
DoCmd.OpenReport strRptName, acViewPreview

DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, strRptName   
        'does not work if you had opened more than one instance of the report

DoCmd.OutputTo ObjectType:=acOutputReport _
            , ObjectName:="" _
            , OutputFormat:=acFormatPDF _
            , OutputFile:=strRetCompletePathPDF _
            , AutoStart:=False _
            , OutputQuality:=acExportQualityPrint
```

very curious and I don't have any idea whats going on

What has been also tested:

I have created a new test procedure and created a simple report. I have successfully generated this report with DoCmd.OutputTo as .xls as well as .pdf.

Then I tested the real procedure using DoCmd.OutputTo as .xls -> works
Then I tested the real procedure with DoCmd.OutputTo as .pdf-> error 2501

For me, the PDF output of my report seems to have a bug.

---

This is what I debugged:

```
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strRptName, acFormatPDF, strRetCompletePathPDF, , , , acExportQualityPrint
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, strRetCompletePathPDF, , , , acExportQualityPrint  '=> ERROR 2487
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, strRetCompletePathPDF, True   '=> Error 2487
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, strRetCompletePathPDF, , , , acExportQualityPrint    '=> Error 2487
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, strRetCompletePathPDF     '=> Error 2501
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "J:\test\SpB2023\Test1.pdf"     '=> Error 2487
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "J:\test\SpB2023\Test1.pdf"     '=> Error 2501
'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "J:\test\SpB2023\Test1.pdf", True     '=> Error 2487
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "J:\test\SpB2023\Test1.pdf", False     '=> Error 2501
```

where error description says:

2501: The OutputTo action was canceled.

2487: The 'ObjectType' argument of this action or method is either not specified or invalid.

Comment: What does the error says? Output operation cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

Hy, Could you try the code bellow.
Don't forget to specify the strFilePath as the complete path where you want the pdf to be generated ...

Modify where needed :

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice", acViewPreview, , "InvoiceID = " & lngInvoiceID
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, strFilePath, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptInvoice"
```